# Converting coordinate results of arcpy.AddXY to Degrees Minutes Seconds Format?

Tags: arcpy, convert, coordinates

I ran the AddXY Coordinates tool on a feature class that did not have any coordinates fields. I now have two fields "POINT_X" and "POINT_Y". My objective is to convert the value in those two fields into degrees/minutes/seconds. I have tried the Convert Coordinate Notation tool but I always get empty fields in for the coordinates. Here is an example of what I am running:

```
arcpy.ConvertCoordinateNotation_management ("Orchids_Layer", "Orchids.shp", "POINT_X", "POINT_Y", "DD_2", "DMS_2","","",sr)
```

[image]

The image shows you the results I get from trying to convert "POINT_X" and "POINT_Y" using the above code. My input file's spatial reference is 'GDA_1994_MGA_Zone_56'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've never used this tool before but it looks like those X/Y values are Easting/Northings not Latitude/Longitudes. Your input_coordinate_format argument, "DD_2", refers to Longitude/Latitude so may be incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a wrong tool. The `Convert Coordinate Notation` tool doesn't support the coordinate system you are using. You should be using the `Add Geometry Attributes` tool instead.

```
arcpy.management.AddGeometryAttributes("Features_", "POINT_X_Y_Z_M", 
                                       None, None, 
                                       "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]")
```

This will add (or in your case, overwrite) two new fields, `POINT_X` and `POINT_Y` to your feature class with the coordinates in DD format (WGS84 coordinate system). If you wish to get coordinates in DMS, now you can use the `Convert Coordinate Notation` tool.